# can we create TrailForce template org without creating TMO?

Tags: trialforce

i have created a Trialforce Source Organization from environment hub. But there is no option to create trailforce template in this org. I donot have any TMO right now. 
Links i have followed are 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/trialforce_create_source_organization.htm#trialforce_create_source_organization

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/trialforce_creating_template.htm#trialforce_creating_template

Is this happing because i don't have a TMO? Or i am missing something?

Comment: Did you read this? **You can create a Trialforce template only if your TSO is less than 256 MB.** Is your TSO small enough to allow templates?

Comment: data storage is only 
106 KB?

Comment: Not sure then. It's been years since I've had a chance to do ISV-style development, so I'm mostly out of the loop on that. Hopefully we can get a good answer from someone with experience on the subject.